# Phusion Passenger/ruby 1.9.3/rails 3.1.3 / [ASYNC BUG] thread_timer: select

Tags: ruby, passenger

I just upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and Rails 3.1.3. And then I re-installed Phusion Passenger with support for nginx. Now nginx is recording the following error on every page access:

> [ASYNC BUG] thread_timer: select
>   EBADF
>
> ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
>
> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or
>   extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details:
>   http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

All of this is on Ubuntu 11.4.

The error trace in the browser looks like this:

```
Passenger encountered the following error:

The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error

#   File                                                                                    Line    Location
0   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    134     in `rescue in start'
1   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    129     in `start'
2   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
3   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  132     in `lookup_or_add'
4   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
5   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  82  in `block in synchronize'
6   < td=""> <> prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
7   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  79  in `synchronize'
8   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   244     in `spawn_rack_application'
9   /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   137     in `spawn_application'
10  /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   275     in `handle_spawn_application'
11  /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     357     in `server_main_loop'
12  /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     206     in `start_synchronously'
13  /opt/gem_home/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

[Passenger before v3.0.11 has issues with Ruby 1.9.3](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=714), updating your Passenger gem and re-installing it should fix the problems.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that did the trick.  I had re-installed phusion-passenger, but it did not update the nginx config file which retained a reference to the old gem:

Comment: @user1082534 It's not supposed to. When you run `passenger-install-nginx-module` it tells you to update the configuration at the end. If this solved your problem, please [click the check mark to accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Im having the same issue except with passenger 3.0.11 on ruby 1.9.3